# Drag/slide to confirm a good alternative to confirmation box?

Tags: interface, verification, error-prevention

While recently making a credit card payment the app asked me to drag the confirm button within a set draggable area to confirm the payment. This is presumably done to reduce the change of accidentally pressing it and costing you money. I found this approach interesting and potentially a good alternative to confirmation prompts of "are you sure you would like to *-action-*" that normally are used to prevent accidental clicks.

**Examples:**

[image]

**(I happen to think these two particular examples aren't the best examples, the left isn't labeled well and the right isn't designed well, but the one I encountered was better looking)**

Are these elements a good alternative to standard confirmation dialogs or are they perhaps more cumbersome/annoying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this form of interaction is only applicable to mobile apps. It would be awkward to perform a slide action with a mouse on desktop. If you are developing solely for the mobile device, this idea is definitely refreshing. It would be ideal in situation where large amount of money is involved and payment that doesn't happen as often (like paying bills or legal services).

However if you are developing for both desktop and mobile, then you might want to consider implementing interaction that is consistent across all platform. The standard "click to pay" method is still more familiar to the wider audience (especially the older generation). Also I imagine this  slide interaction to be cumbersome if I have to buy items every other day. My take is that this form of interaction will not catch on anytime soon.

If "accidental click" is a concern, then a better alternative is to provide user an option to cancel their purchase within a period of time e.g 24 hrs. This gives user a peace of mind and the confidence to use the app.

Comment: "a better alternative is to provide user an option to cancel their purchase within a period of time..."  

When I buy stuff, it should be posted and delivered ASAP - having to wait 24 hrs just in case I regret? No thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are. And if you don't believe me, just ask ... yourself!

If you have a smartphone (I know you do), just remember how many times you slide to answer a phone call. Every. Single. Day.

A lot of times, right? However, this 'slide-to-answer' experience feels so natural and seamless, that you don't even think about it anymore.

P.S.: context *is* King.